# OpenGL-es Sprite Sheets

Tags: opengl-es

I am making a game in OpenGL-es. I have a question, how do you make a sprite sheet in Xcode for you sprite png. Any code examples on how to do the sprite sheets may help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need an external tool. A web search engine is your friend: sprite+sheet+generator+mac

Comment: But i'm asking how to use that for OpenGL-es and what code you can put to make the animation in the game, because I already have the sheet I just need to make it move.